# VSCode/eslint/prettier does not auto-format _app.tsx file on save

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, format, eslint, prettier

I have a fairly extensive eslint/prettier config. Normally it works great, but today I noticed that for some reason my `_app.tsx` file does not auto-format the same as other pages. In this case, it's complaining about `import/order`.

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary'
import '../styles/global.scss'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router' <---- offending line
```

The error is:

```
next/router import should occur before import of react-error-boundary (eslint import/order)
```

Now if I navigate to another file (in this case `Header.tsx` and mix up the import order and save, VS Code automatically reorders the import.

- The interesting bits of my `settings.json`

```
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": false,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.tsx": "typescriptreact"
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "eslint.probe": [
        "javascript",
        "javascriptreact",
        "typescript",
        "typescriptreact",
        "html",
        "markdown"
    ]
}
```

- The interesting bits of my `.eslintrc.cjs`

```
env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'plugin:testing-library/react',
    'plugin:jest-formatting/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:xstate/all',
    'plugin:storybook/recommended',
    'next',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react', 'prettier', 'etc', 'testing-library', 'jest-formatting'],
```

- .prettierrc.json

```
{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "endOfLine": "auto",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "bracketSameLine": false,
  "quoteProps": "as-needed"
}
```

Any ideas? I also noticed it does not `formatOnSave` for config files (like `.prettierrc.json`), but so far I have not found a clear config rule for identifying files to be automatically formatted by VSCode.